# How can I deploy an ASP.NET MVC 5 Web App to a Virtual Network in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, deployment, azure-virtual-network, virtual-network

I have an existing ASP.Net MVC 5 Web Application (and associated web services) that I've been asked to deploy into a specific VNet (virtual network) within Azure. I've googled this to death and struck out.

The best I've found is to edit a ***ServiceConfiguration.cscfg*** file to include a node like this:

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
  <VirtualNetworkSite name="Test-VNet" />
  <AddressAssignments>
    <InstanceAddress roleName="Test-Role-1">
      <Subnets>
        <Subnet name="Subnet-1" />
      </Subnets>
    </InstanceAddress>
  </AddressAssignments>
</NetworkConfiguration>
```

The problem with this is that .cscfg files ***APPEAR*** to be unique to Azure Cloud Service Deployment projects, which don't appear to be of any help when deploying an Azure Web Site. If this is the only way then I'm going to have to create a bunch of Cloud Service projects, port the code into them and then re-test. This is likely to be pretty time-consuming and I don't think that management will appreciate the risk.

Am I going to have to re-create the Web Application projects into Azure Cloud Services to deploy them into VNets, or is there another way...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave in, created Cloud Service projects (with associated deployment packages) to replace the web services and ported the code across. It didn't take too long and required very few code tweaks. The public facing web site I left as a standard Web Application.

Having done this I was able to deploy my private Web Services (now cloud services) into Azure Virtual Networks, where they were hidden from the outside world, and configure the public web site to allow it to access the components within the VNet.

Comment: How exactly did you configure the public web site to allow it to access components within the Vnet? Is there some documentation you can point me to?

I have a VM that I want to limit to only be available to my public azure webapp and am not sure how to do it. I started looking into using ACLs but couldnt get a guaranteed IP and am now looking at using a Vnet.

Comment: You'll need to host your website on the Standard Tier or higher - basic won't allow access to the VNets. After that it's pretty straightforward - you can do it in the new Azure management portal - just select your web app and scroll down to the networking panel at the bottom.

Comment: Hey @Pete - So the only way you found was to create cloud service projects and then move the code in the original project to the new project?
Is  not possible to use a publish profile to deploy to an empty azure web app?